# FactoryGirl and variables inside factory

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins, factory-bot

What if I want to do something like

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :leaf do
  end

  factory :tree do
    l = []
    leaves do
      l << Factory.build(:leaf)
      //some app logic here
      l
    end
    root l.first
  end
end
```

How should I write this to make it work?

And maybe somebody have a link with really complex and untrivial examples of using FactoryGirl?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I've followed what you're asking but would this work?

```
factory :tree do
    after_build { |tree|  
        # build your leaves here
        # ...

        tree.root l.first
    }
end
```